# R function zip(utils) doesn't work on my machine

Tags: r, windows-xp, compression, zip, admin

I would like to use the zip(utils) function, unzip function works fine, however, call zip e.g. zip ("out", "file.txt") does not return the file ("out.zip")  to the working directory and R does not return any message at all - any error message and no massage about successful compression - if compression is successful R returns info such as "deflate - 40%." I checked various R versions and files - zip still doesn't work. On another computers, everything works fine. I have Windows XP. Furthermore, when I type the wrong name of the zip file to compress e.g. zip("out", "this_file_doesnt_exist.txt") R does not return any error at all ! I don't know much about computers, what should I check ? what could be problem in my case ? I turned off antivirus that didn't help.

Comment: Try this code: `library(R.utils); df <- data.frame(x=10); write.csv(df, file="x1.csv"); zip('foo.zip', file = "x.csv"); dir()` Did that work? Do you see a `foo.zip` in your working directory? If not, update your question with the results of `sessionInfo()`

Comment: 1. should be 'file = "x1.csv"' 2. "there is no package called ‘R.utils’" 3. "x1.csv" was created but "foo.zip" wasn't

Comment: Then install the package. `install.packages(R.utils)` first. Then rerun the code.

Comment: 1. Ive installed, zip still doesn't work 2. but zip() is from "utils" library not from "R.utils" so what was the purpose of installing it ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant they have `gzip` if `zip` didn't work for you. That was the point of installing the package. But `zip` works fine for me as is.

Comment: 'gzip' works ! great :D now write it as an answer and I will approve it

Comment: now it works thank you ! write your comment as an answer and I will accept it, mayb you know also how to find out size of file (using R) after compression without writing down compressed file on hard drive ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `gzip` from the package `R.utils`

```
library(R.utils)
df <- data.frame(x=10)
write.csv(df, file="x1.csv")
gzip("x1.csv")
> dir()
[1] "x1.csv.gz"
```

Answer (score 5):

For those reading this on 2020:

Install Rtools (https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/) and follow the documentation steps.

Then Zip command will wokr on Windows 10 machines.

Answer (score 1):

For Windows 10 Users: While the abovementioned `Rtools` approach did not work for me in the context of `zip() {utils}`, package `{zip}` [(package description)](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zip/zip.pdf) works fine without installing `Rtools` and without the need to change your existing code (as the `{zip}` package masks the functions `zip()` and `unzip()` of `{utils}`).